# Change text color based on condition

Tags: php, html, forms

is there an example to change color of the text based on conditions?
for example i want to make condition when `$hasil>=80` it will turn green color, `$hasil>=70` yellow, and below that is red color.

here's my logic code

```php
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $n1 = ($data["nilai_output"]) * 0.7;
    $n2 = ($data["nilai_atasan"]) * 0.1;
    $n3 = ($data["nilai_learning"]) * 0.1;
    $n4 = ($data["nilai_kedisiplinan"]) * 0.05;
    $n5 = ($data["nilai_5r"]) * 0.05;

    $hasil = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4 + $n5);

    if ($hasil >= 95)
    {
        $grade = 1.25;
        $ikk = "istemewa";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 90)
    {
        $grade = 1.10;
        $ikk = "Sangat Memuaskan";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 85)
    {
        $grade = 1.00;
        $ikk = "Memuaskan";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 80)
    {
        $grade = 0.90;
        $ikk = "Cukup Memuaskan";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 75)
    {
        $grade = 0.75;
        $ikk = "Memadai";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 70)
    {
        $grade = 0.50;
        $ikk = "Kurang Memadai";
    }
    elseif ($hasil >= 1)
    {
        $grade = 0.25;
        $ikk = "Tidak Memadai";
    }
    else
    {
        $ikk = "Tidak Berkontribusi";
    }

    $no++;
```

and here's my table column

```
  <td class="font-weight-bold text-danger"><?php echo $hasil;?></td>
  <td class="font-weight-bold text-danger"><?php echo $grade;?></td>
  <td class="font-weight-bold text-danger"><?php echo $ikk;?></td>
```

i want that those three column is using color condition
thanks before

Comment: This does not answer you question but
I suggest using switch statement to avoid this level of unreadable code

Comment: @ShivanshPotdar yea im gonna fix that later, thanks

Comment: @Blizz'ART you can insert css classes from php as well

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava is there some example for that on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
if ($hasil >= 80) {
  $grade = 0.90;
  $color = 'green';
  $ikk = "Cukup Memuaskan";
}elseif($hasil >= 70 && $hasil < 80 ) {
  $grade = 0.75;
  $color = 'yellow';
  $ikk = "Memadai";
}elseif($hasil >= 1 && $hasil < 70 ) {
  $grade = 0.50;
  $color = 'red';
  $ikk = "Kurang Memadai";
}else{
  $ikk = "Tidak Berkontribusi";
}


<td class="font-weight-bold text-danger" style="color:<?=$color;?>"><?php echo $hasil;?></td>
```

I hope this is helps you!

Comment: Please upvote the answer so others can check easily @Blizz'ART

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do what you want. Here's one.

```php
if ($hasil >= 80) {
    $color = 'green';
}
elseif ($hasil >= 70) {
    $color = 'yellow';
}
else {
    $color = 'red';
}
```

then inside your html

```html
<td class="font-weight-bold text-danger <?php echo $color ?>"><?php echo $hasil ?></td>
```

and finally css

```css
.green {
    color: green;
}

.yellow {
    color: yellow;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```